# What's the replacement of python api for “config.labels”

Tags: 14.04, python-2.7

tensorflow 1.0.0

python 2.7.13

Ubuntu 14.04.5

What's the replacement of **python api** for "**config.labels**" ?

```
$ python main_recognize.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_recognize.py", line 27, in <module>
    n_classes = len(cfg.labels)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

**main_recognize.py**:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import config as cfg
import prepare_data as pp_dev_data
import csv
import cPickle
np.random.seed(1515)

# hyper-params
agg_num = 11       # concatenate frames
hop = 1            # step_len
act = 'relu'
n_hid = 500

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

n_input = 440
n_classes = len(cfg.labels)
dropout = 0.6

......
```

I think it must due to the changement of **python api**.

How could I search the replacement of **config.labels** ?

Thanks in advance.